# Sitecore Extranet autologin?

Tags: sitecore

I have a Sitecore 6.6 site with an extranet.
How could i add a autologin feature to the login form?

```
var domain = Sitecore.Context.Domain;
var domainUser = domain.Name + @"\" + Request["username"];
if (Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(domainUser, Request["password"], false))
{
   // SUCCESS
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your login form you will need to provide a checkbox and then check if it is selected. The boolean flag when you login indicates whether you want to persist the login between sessions:

```
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(domainUser, Request["password"], true)
```

You also need to update your `web.config` for the amount of time you want the "remember me" cookie persisted, 1 day = 1440 minutes:

```
<authentication mode="None">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="1440" />
</authentication>
```

http://mazdev.blogspot.ca/2011/06/sitecore-authentication.html